# How to trigger an event when someone clicks the Facebook Like Button? (in Google Tag Manager)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Can you trigger an event when someone clicks this [Facebook Like button](https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/plugins/like.php?action=like&app_id=162193990527434&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FfTmIQU3LxvB.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df3905f9e825b5%26domain%3Dlaopinion.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flaopinion.com%252Ff3cf2d8004936b8%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=838&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FLaOpinionLA&layout=button&locale=es_LA&ref=article_like&sdk=joey&share=false&show_faces=false) which is embeded on articles [like this one](http://laopinion.com/2016/10/31/obama-descarta-que-fbi-quiera-afectar-eleccion/)?

From what I've found so far, it seems hardly possible since the event is taking place on a 3rd party site.

When you  click the button, it changes its text but no event shows up in GTM's previe & debug pane. I also tried AJAX event listeners but that doesn't work either.

Do you know of a way to track this in GTM?

Comment: I tried to fire the event when Click Element > matches CSS selector > single_fb_like (this is the div that contains the two lines of text and the facebook like button)

The problem is that if I click anywhere inside that div except for the like button itself, it will trigger the event. Why isn't the like button click detected? 

Could this be solved with a JQuery code that fires everytime the cursos is focused on that button? I'm curious if anyone's ever dealt with this before. Thanks

Comment: If the Like button is served via a 3rd party (ie. AddThis), then the only way to track the click would be through an API for that 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Facebook has its own [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.8) for picking up events like these. Clickinsight created a custom Google Tag Manager script you can use to send these events through the dataLayer, so you can track them in Google Analytics. Here's the [tutorial](https://www.clickinsight.ca/about/blog/how-to-autotrack-gtm#social-button) on how to do that.